# Multiple form filter GET paramaters

Tags: javascript, html

I have 2 forms GET to filter data, when I submit the first form I have this url
test.com?form1_filter['year']=2022

It works, but now if I want to submit the other form I would like to have
test.com?form2_filter['users']&form1_filter['year']=2022

The problem is when I submit a form, the parameters of the second form were remove

How can I keep all parameters in url ?
I tried in javascript with the event submit when it still remove my parameters.

```
<form id="form1" method="get">
<div>
    <label for="name">Enter your name: </label>
    <input type="text" name="name" id="name" required>
</div>
<div>
    <label for="email">Enter your email: </label>
    <input type="email" name="email" id="email" required>
</div>
<div>
    <input type="submit" value="Filter">
</div>
</form>

<form id="form2" method="get">
<select name="users" id="user-select">
    <option value="1">Dad</option>
    <option value="2">Mom</option>
</select>
<div>
    <input type="submit" value="Filter">
</div>
</form>
```

It's 2 form on the same page

Comment: Please include your code. Are the forms on the same page or separate pages? I would include your original filter as a hidden input in your second form.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Nobody can tell you what's wrong with code we can't see.  Please provide a [mcve] demonstrating the problem.  To learn more about this community and how we can help you, please start with the [tour] and read [ask] and its linked resources.

Comment: What do you use on the server side?

Comment: @user1599011 It's 2 simple form on the same page yes

Comment: @jiwopene On server side I took the information about all the parameters to filter them, but here the parameters of the second form is always remove

Comment: You mentioned javascript, but didn't include it here.

Comment: @user1599011 Because I don't know how to use the js in that case

Comment: But what did you attempt with javascript?

Comment: Take all the parameter and set them in the url after submitting

Answer (score 1):

The form needs to have inputs for all the data you want to appear in the query string.

If you want to copy existing values without displaying a UI control for them, add them as hidden inputs.

```
<input type="hidden" name="form1_filter['year']" value="2022">
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but  I can't add them as hidden because I need the 2 form to be always visible

Comment: Adding a hidden input to a form doesn't make the whole form invisible

Comment: But in your example form1_filter['year'] will be hidden,

Comment: It would still be visible in the first form. It it must be included with the 2nd form, it needs to exist within that form too, and to avoid duplicity, should be hidden.

Comment: In the first form you put a visible input to let the user pick the value of `form1_filter['year']`. In the second form you put a hidden input so the value of `form1_filter['year']` is copied from the previously submitted data.

Answer (score 1):

When you have two form on page that was loaded with URL query string, the newly sent form replaces all the parameters.

The solution is simple: Add `hidden` fields to the form dynamically (using server-side code) that will add the parameters back to the url.

```
<input type=hidden name=field-name value=field-value>
```

You can also do it using JS (not recommended).

Probably better solution is to redirect all requests to other URL that does not use the query string parameters. When query string is added to this URL, also redirect it (to URL that combines both). Example:

```
/foo?field1=bar
  → /foo/field1=bar

/foo/field1=bar?field2=baz
  → /foo/field1=bar,field2=baz
```

The only downside of this approach is that it is more complex on the server side.

Comment: I can't add hidden, because I need my 2 forms with all fields always visible, the 2 forms are not link

Comment: You can add the same hidden fields to both of the forms.

Comment: So I have to put the same fields form 1 in form 2 as hidden, with a lot of field it's complicated, so in Js it's a better solution ?

Comment: With JS, it is not better solution, in my opinion. What do you use for server-side processing of the forms? PHP? Just create a function that constructs the HTML for the hidden fields and add it to both of the forms. It is the simplest solution. *Be sure that you properly escape the field names and values.*

Comment: Yes in PHP, I will do that with session on server side , so I don't have to modify the form with hidden field

Comment: Session is also an option, but it breaks when the user opens the page in two windows (tabs) at once. Imagine this situation: ① One form is modified (and the session is stored). ② In new tab, the same thing is done, but with differend value. ③ In the original tab, the user modifies the form again. What happens now? Do you have result from the tab from step ① or ②?